# Java beginner advancing sum in array

Tags: java, prefix

My program is supposed to take a provided array and create a new array where each element is the sum of the previous elements in original array. For example element one in new array is element one in original array. Element two in new array is sum of element one an element two in original array. Element three in new array is sum of elements one, two and three in original array. I wrote this but I know it is incomplete. Please guide.

```
public class PrefixSum
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[]{0,5,1,-3,2,0,4};
        int[] newArray = new int[7];
        int x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            x = array[i];      
            x = x + i;
        }
        newArray[0] = 0;
        System.out.println(" " + newArray[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `x` supposed to be? Why do you sum up a value and an index?

Comment: You don't do a thing with `newArray`. You need to put some effort into solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `Debug` this code in order to understand the changes.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[]{0,5,1,-3,2,0,4};
    int[] newArray = new int[7];
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        x += array[i];      
        newArray[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code as well. Just providing a working example is not good.

Comment: @mkabanen there is pretty much no details to explain

Comment: there always is. For the beginner programmer it is really important to understand how to solve the problem. So you should explain what is logic behind your code.

Comment: The OP have an incomplete code, all he/she needed is the rest of the code, i can't see possible details to add to my answer. BTW you can downvote it whenever you want. @mkabanen

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variable `runningTotal` to keep count of the running total like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] originalArray = new int[]{0,5,1,-3,2,0,4};
    int[] sumArray = new int[originalArray.length];

    int runningTotal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++){
      runningTotal += originalArray[i];
      sumArray[i] = runningTotal;
    }

    System.out.println("The originalArray is: " + Arrays.toString(originalArray));
    System.out.println("The sumArray is: " + Arrays.toString(sumArray));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The originalArray is: [0, 5, 1, -3, 2, 0, 4]
The sumArray is: [0, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 9]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FEwU/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[]{0,5,1,-3,2,0,4};
    int[] newArray = new int[7];
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];     
        newArray[i]= sum;
        System.out.println(" " +newArray[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.of(0, 5, 1, -3, 2, 0, 4).reduce((left, right) -> {
    sums.add(left + right);
    return left + right;
});
```

Printing `sums` after running yields :

```
[0, 5, 6, 3, 5, 5, 9]
```

Try it [here](https://repl.it/FEwU/1).

Comment: elaborate ...!!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description